# Adding 0X80 + 0X80

Tags: hex, conditional-statements, bit, flags

As a preparation for my exam in Microcontrollers, I have this question:
How are the condition bits set when the Byte operation 0x80 + 0x80 is executed?
I understand how to add those 2, but I get 256 and I don't know which condition bits are set in this case.

Answer (score 1):

First, the highest value one byte can hold is `255 (0xFF)`, so I do not think the result would be 256, but rather, overflow would cause the resulting value to be `0 (0x00)`.

Secondly, the condition bits would depend on your processor, but going by some [ARM notes](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/condition-codes-1-condition-flags-and-codes), I might reasonably expect:

> #### Z: Zero
>
> The Z flag is set if the result of the flag-setting instruction is zero.
>
> #### C: Carry (or Unsigned Overflow)
>
> The C flag is set if the result of an unsigned operation overflows the 32-bit result register. This bit can be used to implement 64-bit unsigned arithmetic, for example.